# Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Promise<void | AxiosResponse>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I am getting this error:

```
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Promise<void | AxiosResponse<{ data: { email: string; username: string; }; }, any>>'.ts(2339)
```

while I do the post request like this:

```
const sendRequest = async (params: LoginProps) => {
    const res = axios
      .post<{ data: { email: string; username: string } }>(
        'http://localhost:3333',
        {
          ...params,
        }
      )
      .catch((err) => console.log('errors', err));

    const data = await res.data; //error is here
    return data;
  };
```

how to handle this? any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `await` keyword before `axios.post`.
Then get the data like this :

```
const data = res && res.data
```

This is because `axios` is `async` and needs to be awaited to fetch the data.